# Why isn't my status code working on PyCharm (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code which I tried making to have my bot status saying how many servers he is in. But there is an error and PyCharm says that `bot` doesn't have the attribute `servers`. How do I fix it?

```
await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Game(name="on " + str(len(bot.servers)) + " Servers.", type=0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bot.servers` does not exist. Use `bot.guilds` instead.

````py
await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Game(name="on " + str(len(bot.guilds)) + " Servers.", type=0))```
````